# Adjusting and reindexing a drifting time index dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have a dataset with an average interval of 22.xx seconds between recordings while the median interval is 21 seconds.

I tried to use the `DatetimeIndex.`[floor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor)/[ceil](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.ceil.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.ceil)/[round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.round.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.round) functions (with 20/21/22 second frequencies), but these lead to duplicated indices and I need to subsequently merge the dataframe with another one, therefore, duplicated indices have to be avoided. Dropping duplicated indices also leads to significant data loss.

I want the dataframe to use an equidistant time interval, preferably rounded to 00/20/40 seconds.

A few sample rows of the data are shown below.

```
2018-05-06 18:02:24    1.15e+07
2018-05-06 18:02:45    1.35e+07
2018-05-06 18:03:05    1.08e+07
...
2018-05-06 18:08:30    1.11e+07
2018-05-06 18:08:50    1.20e+07
2018-05-06 18:09:10    1.30e+07
...
```

Which when processed should return the following.

```
2018-05-06 18:02:20    1.15e+07
2018-05-06 18:02:40    1.35e+07
2018-05-06 18:03:00    1.08e+07
...
2018-05-06 18:08:20    1.11e+07
2018-05-06 18:08:40    1.20e+07
2018-05-06 18:09:00    1.30e+07
...
```

Rounding causes the above to have duplicated indices, while `floor` and `ceil` also cause duplicated indices.

Any suggestions on how to adjust the drift without losing too much data?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add new `DataFrame` sample for merge with expected output? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jezrael I added a sample of the required version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working [`DatetimeIndex.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.round.html) by `20S` for 20 seconds:

```
df.index = df.index.round('20S')
print (df)
                            col
2018-05-06 18:02:20  11500000.0
2018-05-06 18:02:40  13500000.0
2018-05-06 18:03:00  10800000.0
2018-05-06 18:08:40  11100000.0
2018-05-06 18:08:40  12000000.0
2018-05-06 18:09:20  13000000.0
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) - it create `DatetimeIndex` with consecutive values:

```
df = df.resample('20S').mean() 
print (df)

                            col
2018-05-06 18:02:20  11500000.0
2018-05-06 18:02:40  13500000.0
2018-05-06 18:03:00  10800000.0
2018-05-06 18:03:20         NaN
2018-05-06 18:03:40         NaN
2018-05-06 18:04:00         NaN
2018-05-06 18:04:20         NaN
2018-05-06 18:04:40         NaN
2018-05-06 18:05:00         NaN
2018-05-06 18:05:20         NaN
2018-05-06 18:05:40         NaN
2018-05-06 18:06:00         NaN
2018-05-06 18:06:20         NaN
2018-05-06 18:06:40         NaN
2018-05-06 18:07:00         NaN
2018-05-06 18:07:20         NaN
2018-05-06 18:07:40         NaN
2018-05-06 18:08:00         NaN
2018-05-06 18:08:20  11100000.0
2018-05-06 18:08:40  12000000.0
2018-05-06 18:09:00  13000000.0
```

Then is possible remove this values:

```
df = df.resample('20S').mean().dropna(how='all') 
print (df)
                            col
2018-05-06 18:02:20  11500000.0
2018-05-06 18:02:40  13500000.0
2018-05-06 18:03:00  10800000.0
2018-05-06 18:08:20  11100000.0
2018-05-06 18:08:40  12000000.0
2018-05-06 18:09:00  13000000.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this, and since there is a drift, the duplication will occur still. I also added the frequencies I tried already to the question.

Comment: @AtifRaza - Can you create some data with returned duplications? And then add expected output? Most close to real data.

Comment: I added the entries causing index duplication when using `round`. Can you please also comment if using resampling with `mean` could solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @AtifRaza - Yes, resample with `mean` create unique `DatetimeIndex`, like `df = df.resample('20S').mean()`

Comment: Great. If you add the resampling bit to the answer it would be better. Then I can accept that. Thanks again.